# Apply a default loadout for all heroes

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

With Heroes of the Storm 2.0 update, you can apply a loadout with skins, mounts, sprays and voicelines for specific heroes. You can even save multiple loadouts!

The issue I am having is that I can't find a way to apply a "default" loadout with all my best cosmetics to all heroes. I have to go into every hero and make the same loadout over and over.

Is there a way to apply a default loadout to all heroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, at the moment there isn't a default loadout por all heroes. Either a loadout that change if you get new cosmetic thing, or a random loadout, that for me, I want this more than other.

The 2.0 patch still on "beta" for me. There is some information on the statistics that are wrong or just missed information. 2.0 only have 3 days of life so, in a future it will be for sure.

Comment: Defaults has been mentioned as a desirable by the devs. Unfortunately it didn't make the 2.0 patch when it went live to my knowledge.